# Identify directions of similar triangles in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry, hough-transform, invariants

I have a **BW bitmap of similar triangles**. I am trying to identify the **direction** each triangle is facing. By *"facing"* I mean describing the direction in a way what is constant across all triangles, by for example the direction of the longest side's median.

So far I could identify the triangles individually, but I don't know what would be the best way to find out the direction of each triangle.

As a first idea I thought about using **Hough transform** to **fit lines for the sides** of each individual triangle. Once I have the 3 sides, I can **calculate their intersections** and then I have the coordinates of the 3 vertices. From the 3 vertices it’s easy to find out the longest side's median.

My problem with this approach is that I never used Hough transforms and I don't know how hard it is to write a function which finds the sides and returns them in a way what I can use for calculating intersections. Can you link me to some article or explain briefly **how to use Hough transform to find sides** in a representation what I can use for calculating intersections?

My other idea is to use **[rotation invariant moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moments#Rotation_invariant_moments)**, directly on the bitmap images, without recognising their sides by Hough transform.

My problem with this solution is that I don't know what is the *"meaning"* of a direction when I describe it using moments. **If I use invariant moments, how can I define a reference direction?**

A sample image with the identified objects:
[image: sample]

A single object
[image: sample1]

Comment: Yes, and actually they are 45-45-90. But it would be interesting to know the general solution when they are just ordinary triangles.

Comment: Could you post a link to a bitmap with just one triangle?

Comment: I uploaded it to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`houghlines`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/houghlines.html) to find the longest *in each triangle* i.e. the BW input should only contain the *edges* of one triangle (e.g. use `BW = edge(I,'canny')`). This will give you the equation of the longest side to your triangle.

If your triangles are isoceles, then the normal to the longest side passing through its midpoint is the median, and you're done.

If not, I guess you'll have to find the 3 edges, etc.

#### Update:

Looking at your blobs, I'd recommend experimenting with `R = regionprops(BW,'Orientation');`